# Isuue for get all months from a year and get all weeks from a month using Moment js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

am a new for moment.js

***i want 3 type of outputs***

- Get all months from a year
- get all weeks from a month in Moment js
- get all days from a week

How can i do this using moment.js?

I have tried for get all month

```
moment().months(2011);// it's working for my year is 2011
```

but i have only last 2 digits of year.

```
moment().months(11);// It's give wrong values or my year is 11
```

I also read the document, they said

`moment().months()` Accepts numbers from 0 to 11. If the range is exceeded, it will bubble up to the year.

**This problem also accrued when i use get days and weeks**

How can i solve this problem in moment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a date as parameter (12-12-2011) find year month, month week, and week day numerical values, if you need words (Monday, December) values just use format of moment.js and translations.

A bit incorrect what you do with moment().months(2011) - moment() return date time now, months(value) add value months to your moment check and see:

```
moment().months(2011).format("LLLL"); //result Tuesday, August 27, 2182 ...
```

Now read a bit about year last week [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) variations between (52/53).

Now the solution for your problem,

get all months of the year, dude seriously (12 months) anyway:

```
 moment("12-26-2011", "MM-DD-YYYY").month() + 1;
```

get weeks of the year not of the month (you will be confuzed using week of month)

```
 moment("12-26-2011", "MM-DD-YYYY").week();
```

or try this (month week):

```
var curr_month = moment("12-26-2011", "MM-DD-YYYY").month(); 
var prev_month_last_week = moment("01-01-2011", "MM-DD-YYYY").add(curr_month -1, "month").week();
var your_week_per_month = moment("12-26-2011", "MM-DD-YYYY").week() - prev_month_last_week; //from 1 to 4:
```

Day of the week:

```
moment("12-26-2011", "MM-DD-YYYY").day();
```

Hope it's helpful.